# Reduce opacity throught setInterval

Tags: javascript

I tried too write simple function similar to fadeOut from jQuery, but stuck. Everything works, but opacity reduces from 0.02 not from 1, as I write in css. Inspecting code by console.log() show on first step empty, then -0.02, -0,04. Here is my code css:

```
#box {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  opacity:1;
  width: 200px;
}
```

JS:

```
 var box = document.getElementById("box");

 setInterval(function() {
  console.log(box.style.opacity);
  box.style.opacity -= 0.02;
 }, 1000)
```

Here is codepen http://codepen.io/Kuzyo/pen/xDc
Can somebody explain whats going on. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to clear that interval once the opacity hits 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) when you read a CSS property.

```
 box.style.opacity = window.getComputedStyle(box).opacity - 0.02;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aCKNz/

Comment: `element.style` represents the element's inline style (`<div style="...">`) only, not what's in external CSS declarations.

Comment: Here is tut for this script http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/javascript-from-null-chapter-4/ but window.getComputedStyle() didn't use. I did everything as here for me it doesn't work :(

Comment: @kuzyoy The tutorial uses inline styles, which is why `.style` works for them.

Answer (score 1):

`element.style.opacity` only responds to the style if it is defined in the `style="..."` attribute of the element, not if it's in the stylesheet.

Try this instead:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
(function(){var o=1;setTimeout(function(){box.style.opacity=o-=0.2;if(o>0)setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000);},1000);})();
```

Or, in its expanded form:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
(function(){
    var o=1;
    setTimeout(function(){
        o -= 0.2;
        box.style.opacity = o;
        if(o>0) setTimeout(arguments.callee,1000);
    },1000);
})();
```